# glm running out of memory in 64-bit R?

Tags: r

I am trying to run glm on a dataset with 255001 data points, but it's saying

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 10.0 Gb
```

This is very strange because when I start up R, I see the message

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) -- "Sock it to Me"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Which seems to indicate that I'm running a 64 bit version of R, and I read that the memory limit for 64 bit versions of R on Unix is on the order of 128 Tb.

Furthermore, I have successfully run glm logistic regression on very similar datasets that are twice as large without any problem.

How can I reconcile these facts, and how can I get R to hold large objects in memory?

Comment: Could it be that your computer is running out of memory (rather than R itself)?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html, [a potential reconciliation](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-November/260903.html), and maybe call `gc()` to free up some memory?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a bug in my code, and when I was reading in the data, I set `header=FALSE` instead of `header=TRUE`.  Changing this fixed the problem.